# Can't locate DBI.pm in @INC with Perl

Tags: linux, perl

I'm new in Perl, I installed the DBI module but when I try to run my script I get this error:

```
Can't locate DBI.pm in @INC (you may need to install the DBI module) (@INC contains:
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20/DBI.pm
    /home/heisenberg/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/lib/site_perl/5.20.1/x86_64-linux
    /home/heisenberg/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/lib/site_perl/5.20.1
    /home/heisenberg/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/lib/5.20.1/x86_64-linux
    /home/heisenberg/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/lib/5.20.1
    .
    ) at call_request.pl line 12.
```

[Line breaks added for readability]

I know there is another topic with the same subject but no answer. I have no idea what I can do.. ?

I'm on linux (ubutunu)

Thanks for help !

Edit :

Output :

```
perl est /home/heisenberg/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/bin/perl

cpan est /home/heisenberg/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/bin/cpan

#!/home/heisenberg/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/bin/perl
    eval 'exec /home/heisenberg/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    if $running_under_some_shell;

grep arg
    make_arg           []
    make_install_arg   []
    makepl_arg         [INSTALLDIRS=site]
    mbuild_arg         []
    mbuild_install_arg []
    mbuildpl_arg       [--installdirs site]

PERLBREW_PERL: perl-5.20.1
PERLBREW_VERSION: 0.73
PERLBREW_ROOT: /home/heisenberg/perl5/perlbrew
PERLBREW_MANPATH: /home/heisenberg/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/man
PERLBREW_HOME: /home/heisenberg/.perlbrew
PERLBREW_BASHRC_VERSION: 0.73
PERLBREW_PATH: /home/heisenberg/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/home/heisenberg/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/bin
PERL5LIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20/DBI.pm
```

Comment: Like i said i already installed the DBI module

Comment: Perl disagrees.

Comment: Is the module installed in a different directory?

Comment: Why do you have a `.pm` file listed directly in `@INC`? Why do you have `/5.20/` and `/5.20.1/` in `@INC`? Did you install DBI for Perl 5.20, upgrade to 5.20.1 and then try to hack the old DBI.pm into your `@INC` install of just installing it properly for the new perl?

Comment: I have no idea @Quentin ... ! i installed DBI with cpan and the command line install DBI

Comment: I'd guess you installed DBI for a different perl and the weird entry .pm in @INC is you trying to work around that; don't do that.  Do `perlbrew use perl-5.20.1; cpan DBI`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install DBI using the `perl` for which you want available. You said you've already done this, but that's obviously not the case. Normally, you'd do the following, but maybe you have a messed up system

```
perlbrew use perl-5.20.1
cpan DBI
```

If that doesn't work, add the output of the following to your question and notify me you've done this by leaving a comment.

```
perlbrew use perl-5.20.1
type perl
type cpan
head -n 3 "$( type -p cpan )"
echo "o conf" | cpan | grep arg
perl -E'say "$_: $ENV{$_}" for grep /^PERL/, keys %ENV'
```

PS - Whatever you did to add `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20/DBI.pm` to `@INC` is wrong! Get rid of it.

---

The problems were caused by the use `su`, which would cause the system `perl` to be used instead of the `perlbrew`-installed `perl`.

Comment: for the last perl -MDBI -e1, it's the same output as my error

Comment: `PERL5LIB` should be unset, but it's not causing any harm. Bad paths are simply ignored.

Comment: Sorry for the million questions, but it's because everything looks right! One more: `find /home/heisenberg/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1 -name 'DBI.pm'` It makes no sense that `perl` running `cpan` can see it, but the same `perl` can't otherwise.

Comment: For the find there is no output.. Yeah all looks right but always have this error ^

Comment: So it's not installed, but `cpan` says it is?!?! I don't know, but I think you should be able to install it using `perl -MCPAN -e'install DBI'`

Comment: With this i have the output Reading '/home/heisenberg/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Tue, 09 Jun 2015 12:17:01 GMT
DBI is up to date (1.633).

Comment: wut? `echo '! print "\n$^X\n"' | cpan | grep /home`

Comment: /home/heisenberg/.cpan
    /home/heisenberg/.cpan/.lock
/home/heisenberg/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/bin/perl

Comment: `mv ~/.cpan ~/.cpan.bk ; cpan DBI` (This renames the directory that contains your CPAN settings and the temporary build directory `cpan` uses.)

Comment: One last: `PERL5LIB= cpan DBI`

Comment: Reading '/home/heisenberg/.cpan/Metadata' Database was generated on Tue, 09 Jun 2015 12:17:01 GMT DBI is up to date (1.633).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80084/discussion-between-ikegami-and-clement-andraud).

Comment: In `/home/heisenberg/.cpan/build` do you see `DBI-*` directories?  If so, go into one of them and run: `/home/heisenberg/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/bin/perl Makefile.PL` and then `make install` to force a new manual install.  Where did it put the `DBI.pm`?